# Attachments.Add() missing multiple files

Tags: c#

Please check the simple mail method bellow. For test purpose i have attaching two file manually by file location path string as u can see on- `mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users...`
But the problem with this method is when i run it the first attachment is getting attached with email but missing second one always. Whats wrong i am doing here? Any idea?
Thanks in advance

```
public static bool SendEmail(string password, string from, string to, string cc, string subject, string[] attachedFiles, string body, string host, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);


                //foreach (var attachedFile in attachedFiles)
                //{
                //    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachedFile.ToString()));
                //}


                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users\liaka\Desktop\Jordan\FileMailer\FileMailer\Backlog_07_12_2018.xlsx"));
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users\liaka\Desktop\Jordan\FileMailer\FileMailer\test.txt"));

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.CC.Add(cc);

                var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, password),
                    EnableSsl = true
                };
                client.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists, is accessible, and has content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my check your `MailMessage()` method usage looks good. I have tested my self and it was working just fine with multiple attached files. Now only thing you can check which are-

1) Your files are really exists on your provided file path. (check by visiting that path with windows file explorer address bar)

2) The file you are trying to attach (specially which one is missing) that is not empty file (because when i run test empty file were not getting attached however make test with gmail SMTP)

If above things are correct then i think this could be issue with your other email settings?

Comment: Hay one file was empty, the second one. this works now. Thanks